# R Linux error while trying to install apackage

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I am quite new to R on Linux, and I was trying to install the package DMRcate via the BiocManager command. I kept receiving the error message that

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack: No such file or directory`
`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas: No such file or directory`

It seems like the installation or compilation of certain dependency packages could not be carried out because of these errors.

In addition, the last line of the compilation before this error message pops up is as follows.

`g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o edgeR.so R_add_prior_count.o R_ave_log_cpm.o R_calculate_cpm.o R_check_poisson_bound.o R_compute_apl.o R_compute_nbdev.o R_exact_test_by_deviance.o R_fit_levenberg.o R_fit_one_group.o R_get_one_way_fitted.o R_initialize_levenberg.o R_loess_by_col.o R_maximize_interpolant.o R_process_hairpin_reads.o R_simple_good_turing.o add_prior.o adj_coxreid.o fmm_spline.o glm_levenberg.o glm_one_group.o init.o interpolator.o nbdev.o objects.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR`

Can anyone help me with this issue? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: on ubuntu `sudo apt install libopenblas-dev` will give you lapack lib and then should build

Comment: Thanks, Chris! The package has been installed successfully after incorporating your suggestion.